# Selenium(WebDriver) Cannot find and click element: <a class="page-next" href="javascript:gotoPage(2)"></a>

Tags: c#, javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver

-Hello, thank you for reading my post. I have spent all day trying to figure this out. Just trying to click the above element to iterate to the next page of product reviews (this doesn't change the URL). The element corresponds to the "next" button on the product feedback section of the page.

Here is My code:

```
using OpenQA;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
```

....

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Wholesale-DIY-Cardboard-Hang-tag-Retro-Gift-Hang-tag-500pcs-lot-Free-shipping-Thank-you/538222647.html");

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[10]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")).Click();
```

The above click command is just to open the product feedback section of the webpage (it works). Next I just want to select the next page of the product feedback but haven't been successful.Below are some commands that I've tried to click the next button and move to the next page of the product feedback listings. I'm new to programming, as you can probably see.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a[3]")).Click();
NoSuchElementException was unhandled: Unable to locate element: "method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a[3]"}"

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class,'page-next')]")).Click();
NoSuchElementException was unhandled:Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@class,'page-next')]"}

       driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a[@href='javascript:gotoPage(2)]")).Click(); 
InvalidSelectorException was unhandled: The given selector /html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a[@href='javascript:gotoPage(2)] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:

InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a[@href='javascript:gotoPage(2)] because of the following error:

[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "file:///C:/Users/Danny/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous695678260.webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js Line: 5773"]

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='javascript:gotoPage(2)]")).Click(); 
InvalidSelectorException was unhandled: The given selector //a[@href='javascript:gotoPage(2)] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:

InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@href='javascript:gotoPage(2)] because of the following error:  

[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "file:///C:/Users/Danny/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2137829175.webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js Line: 5773"]         

driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("2")).Click();
```

`No error` here, but this code clicks the wrong button on the page.

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("javascript:gotoPage(2)")).Click();   
NoSuchElementException was unhandled: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"javascript:gotoPage(2)"}

driver.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).FindElement(By.LinkText("Next")).Click();
NoSuchElementException was unhandled: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Next"}

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("html body.product-evaluation div#transction-feedback div.rating-detail div.topnav div#pagination-top.pagination div.pos-right a.page-next")).Click();
NoSuchElementException was unhandled: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"html body.product-evaluation div#transction-feedback div.rating-detail div.topnav div#pagination-top.pagination div.pos-right a.page-next"}

IJavaScriptExecutor JavascriptExecutor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

JavascriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("gotoPage(2)");
"Unexpected error. ReferenceError: gotoPage is not defined"

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]")).Click();
```

No error, nothing happens

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("css=a.page-next")).Click(); 

InvalidSelectorException was unhandeled:The given selector css=a.page-next is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:[Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12" nsresult: "0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)"  location: "file:///C:/Users/Danny/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous797491401.webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js Line: 7717"]

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='pagination-top']/div/a[2]"));

NoSuchElementException was unhandled:Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='pagination-top']/div/a[2]"}
```

I've also tried:automation in Internet Explorer, and waiting for the page to load fully before proceeding.

Comment: Are you getting an 'ElementNotFound' type of exception each time? If not, what is the exception/error/failure state you are receiving?

Comment: Hello, Nashibukasan. I will place each error underneath the code

Comment: @Danny Are you sure, that the nextpage button is not present inside a frame?

Comment: Hi HemChe. Yes it is inside a frame. I don't know what a frame is so it didn't occur to me that this could be part of the problem. Now I see that there is a lot of information about accessing elements within a frame, so I will look into it and hopefully find a solution, thanks.

Comment: @HemChe the element does seem to be in an iframe. I couldn't find the name or id of the frame so i tried to switch the IWebDriver using indexs, for example: 
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1);
... (up to 20) It turned out that the only index that didn't throw a  NoSuchFrameException was 0. Does that mean there is only one frame?

Comment: @Danny Okay. Let us know if you still see an issue even after switching to frame.

Comment: @HemChe, sorry accidentally submitted my comment before i finished. Yes, still seem to be having the same exceptions in Frame(0)

Comment: @Danny After switching to frame(0) did you check for isDisplayed() function for the nextpage button? If so, is it returning true?

Comment: @HemChe Even though everyone is talking about using the isDisplayed() method online, I don't seem to have it. Instead of isDisplayed() and isVisable() I have 'Displayed' and 'Visable'. So I tried them with a few different FindElement commands but I could not create the IWebElement without the same exceptions:  <br/>IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("page-next"));  <br/>
bool displayedResult = element.Displayed;    <br/>  Also...

Comment: After loading Frame(0) and waiting until the page was fully loaded like Nashibukasan suggested, this command worked a couple of times:     driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='pagination-top']/div/a[2]")).Click();   But then it gave the same Exception for the next 8 trys, even thought I waited for a long time for the page to be loaded. Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the situation I am focusing on:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class,'page-next')]")).Click();
```

*NoSuchElementException was unhandled:Unable to locate element:* `{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@class,'page-next')]"}`

I would suggest that you must add in a method prior to searching for the element, to wait for its existence on the page. I feel that the element you are searching for has not been loaded on the page by the time you try to search for it so Selenium instantly fails. I would suggest going to [this link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and using either an Implicit or Explicit wait. I feel this is the issue because your XPath looks correct according to the HTML in your title.

The difference between these is that Implicit waits are set for *each time you search for an element only* while Explicit waits can have any condition to wait for and can have a different timeout for each case. Read the link provided and see if it makes sense, if not please post your attempt and I will try to help.

Comment: Hello again Nashibukasan. Thanks for your response and explaining the difference between implicit and explicit waits. I didn't add the method to my code just yet but I put a breakpoint in the code just before the the line of code that always fails. I waited until I could see the next button appear in my browser before I clicked continue in visual studio. Unfortunately i still got the same error messages.

Comment: I've just noticed that you don't necessarily need the 'contains' part of your xpath. In fact, you might not have to use XPath at all! Try this: `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("page-next")).Click();`

Comment: Thanks Nashibukasan. I tried the FindElement command but it didn't work. After loading a new frame and waiting a long time for the page to load I did get on of FindElement commands to Click but then it would work again after that, so it seems like some other random factor.

Comment: Just a as a follow up I noticed that when went to another place with a better internet connection the problem went away (provided I used proper waits and frame switch of course)

Comment: If a better (faster) Internet connection effects the result this must be a timing issue. Keep trying waits until you get a result.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem today with the following xpath:
//a[@class='myclass' and Text()='My Special link']

I was supposed to verify the syntax in firebug using the xpath tool, and it found the element. In java code it thrown the very same exception as you. I discovered the lil thing that was wrong was "Text()" I changed it to "text()" and it works. Subtle case sensitive problem lol.

I also saw in another forum a similar syntax issue, like:
//[@class='myclass' and Text()='My Special link']

I guess the person wanted to find anything with class "myclass", it didn't work. It worked when an * was added, though.
//*[@class='myclass' and Text()='My Special link']

Take a look to the syntax of your xpath,

cheers!